# Export "save as a web page" from RStudio viewer returning error related to rprojroot package

Tags: html, r, rstudio

I am trying to export a R leaflet map

```
library(leaflet)
leaflet() %>% addTiles()
```

in HTML using the export button in RStudio Viewer (from menu picking option "Save as a web page...") and I get an error window saying:

*"Required package versions could not be found:
rprojroot 1.0 is not available
Check that getOption("repos") refers to a CRAN repository that contains the needed  package versions"*

I tried to install rprojroot

```
install.packages("rprojroot")
```

but getting the warning:

*"package ‘rprojroot’ is available as a source package but not as a binary
Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘rprojroot’ is not available (as a binary package for R version 3.1.3)"*

My session info are:

*R version 3.1.3 (2015-03-09)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 8 x64 (build 9200)*

Is there a way to overpass this error and export the map as a web page or with my R version (3.1.3) I am prevented to do that because of rprojroot unavailability? Thanks, Jacopo

Comment: Why can't you update R to 3.3.x? rprojroot installs fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like several people are having this issue after updating RStudio. I was having the trouble trying to knit html from RStudio. This is how I fixed it. I confess that I can't explain exactly what the problem is or why this worked, but it worked for me when receiving the exact same error.

```
install.packages("rprojroot", type="source")
```

When I tried to knit, it still did not work and asked to install a few packages from a popup. This did not work so I had to install each of them manually from the console.

Comment: Thanks Scott. I can't tell you if your solution work for me because finally I've just updated to 3.3 to avoid the problem.